# Create a resource POST with a GenericForeignKey in TastyPie

Tags: python, django, tastypie

TastyPie shows [here](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/content_types.html) how to list **ContentTypes** and **GenericForeignKeys**. I have this working, but how do you make a **POST** to create a resource that has Generic Foreign Key?

**This is my resource:** I want to now create a new campaign while also creating a new SingleVoucherReward or MultiVoucherReward at the same time then linking it. How can this be done in TastyPie?

```
class CampaignCreateResource(ModelResource):
    """
    API Facet.
    """
    user = fields.ToOneField(UserResource, 'user',  full=True)

    participant_reward = GenericForeignKeyField({
        SingleVoucherReward: SingleVoucherResource,
        MultiVoucherReward: MultiVoucherResource,
    }, 'participant_reward')

    class Meta:
        queryset = Campaign.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'campaign'
        allowed_methods = ['post', 'get']
        authentication = APIAuthentication().get_authentication()
        authorization = UserObjectsOnlyAuthorization()
        validation = FormValidation(form_class=CampaignForm)
        excludes = ['id', 'participant_reward_object_id']

    def hydrate(self, bundle, request=None):
        """
        Tastypie uses a 'hydrate' cycle to take serializated data from the client
        and turn it into something the data model can use.
        """
        bundle.obj.user = get_user_model().objects.get(pk=bundle.request.user.id)
        return bundle
```

Comment: Not sure about the best way to do this in Tastypie but if you have real models for SingleVoucherReward and MultiVoucherReward then you could use a Django signal of post save connect to create those models on the create of Campaign. More info here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/

Comment: @mconlin thanks for your response is there a way this can be done in the JSON post i.e. {name:123, participant_reward:{title:123, code:123},}

Comment: I am not sure.. Could you override obj_create and do it yourself? Something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12264949/django-tastypie-update-two-models